# Making the 'www' header not matter using DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth, google-openid

I'm experimenting with DotNetOpenAuth and I realized (at least as far as Google goes) if I registered with www.domain.com my claimed identifier is different than domain.com.

I had the impression setting the realm would fix this issue but it didnt.

For now I believe I have solved the problem using url rewriting.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the realm so that it always includes the `www.` prefix or never does will in fact fix this problem.  However you must also make sure that the ReturnUrl (i.e. return_to) has the same host name as the realm so you may have to apply the same modifier to that as you do to the realm.